# would remove a key from Dictionary in foreach cause a problem? or should I better to construct a new Dictionary?

Tags: c#

for example:

1.

```
         foreach (var item in myDic)
                {
                  if (item.value == 42)
                        myDic.remove(item.key);
                }
```

would the iterator works properly no matter how the statements in the inner brackets could possibly affect `myDic`?

2.

```
    var newDic = myDic.where(x=>x.value!=42).ToDictionary(x=>x.key,x=>x.value);
```

Is 2nd approach a good practice? functional programming and immutable?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The first approach will crash at runtime, since the enumerator makes sure that nobody deletes from the underlying collection while it's enumerating.

The second approach is a nice thought, but C# dictionaries are mutable and it's neither  idiomatic nor efficient to copy them around if you can accomplish the same thing with mutation.

This is a typical way:

```
var itemsToRemove = myDic.Where(f => f.Value == 42).ToArray();
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
    myDic.Remove(item.Key);
```

---

EDIT:  In response to your question in the comments.  Here's how the example in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175137/can-i-assign-the-result-of-a-linq-query-to-the-source-variable-of-the-same-query) works:

```
myList = myList.where(x=>x>10).select(x=>x-10);
```

This line of code doesn't run anything; it's totally lazy.  Let's say for the sake of argument that we have a `foreach` after it to make it look more like this question's example.

```
foreach (int n in myList)
    Console.WriteLine(n);
```

When that executes, here's what'll happen on each iteration:

1. Call `MoveNext` on the enumerator
2. The enumerator finds the next value greater than ten
3. Then it takes that value minus ten and sets the `Current` property to that
4. Binds the `Current` property to the variable `n`
5. `Console.WriteLine`s it

You can see that there's no mystery and no infinite loop and no whatever.

Now compare to my example, supposing we left out the `ToArray`.

```
var itemsToRemove = myDic.Where(f => f.Value == 42);
foreach (var item in itemsToRemove)
    myDic.Remove(item.Key);
```

1. Call `MoveNext` on the enumerator
2. The enumerator finds the next pair with value 42 and sets the `Current` property to that
3. Binds the `Current` property to the variable `item`
4. `Remove`s it

This doesn't work because while it's perfectly fine to `WriteLine` something from a collection while you have an enumerator open on it, you aren't permitted to `Remove` something from a collection while you have an enumerator open on it.

If you call `ToArray` up front, then you start out by enumerating over the dictionary and populating the array.  When we get to the `foreach`, the `foreach` statement has an enumerator open on the *array*, not the dictionary.  You're allowed to remove from the dictionary as you iterate over the array.

Comment: `ToList()` is faster than `ToArray()`.

Comment: The performance difference is insignificant enough that I usually just prefer whichever seems more semantically correct (that is, if I don't plan on adding or removing, I stick with `ToArray`.)

Comment: @mquander: why do u need `toarray()`? can i omit that since `where` returns `ienumerable`?

Comment: No, you can't omit it.  If you left it lazy, then it would still be enumerating over the dictionary when `Remove` is called, and you'd be right back where you started (with an exception at runtime.)  You need to do all the work to build the list of items to remove before you actually start removing any.

Comment: @mquander: hmm, i am kind of confused when I should cache the lazy list and when not necessary. could u plz check another question posted by me earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175137/can-i-assign-the-result-of-a-linq-query-to-the-source-variable-of-the-same-query

Comment: @mquander : Regarding "since the enumerator makes sure that nobody deletes from the underlying collection while it's enumerating". This is the case for the List, Dictionary and other class like this, but should he use a custom dictionary class, he could implement the iterator in such way it wouldn't crash if you remove an element when iterating, right? (not saying he should, just saying he could) That would however require him to write the full state machine code instead of just using yield return.

Comment: @Tipx: Sure, he could do that if he really wanted to.  He'd need to return a custom class implementing `IEnumerator` from `GetEnumerator`.  @colinfang:  I'll elaborate in my answer in a moment -- this box is too small to make it clear.

Comment: @mquander: Have you missed .select(x=>x.key) in order to reform the dictionary into list?

Comment: Why not a one-liner? `myDic.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == 42).ToList.ForEach(kvp => myDic.Remove(kvp.Key));`

Answer (score 16):

Also you can iterate over the *copy* of your collection:

```
foreach (var item in myDic.ToList())
{
    if (item.value == 42)
    myDic.remove(item.key);
}
```

notice `myDic.ToList()` in `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 13):

According to the docs, starting from .NET Core 3.0, removing an element will no longer affect active enumerators. You can safely remove an item while iterating:

```
foreach (var item in myDic)
{
    if (item.Value == 42)
        myDic.Remove(item.Key);
}
```

[Dictionary<TKey,TValue>.Remove Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.remove)

> .NET Core 3.0+ only: this mutating method may be safely called without invalidating active enumerators on the Dictionary<TKey,TValue> instance. This does not imply thread safety.

Comment: amazing, how did u notice this? Is there any more in depth details how they manage to implement that internally? I am unable to find it in .net core release note

Comment: @colinfang Having read this thread, I stumbled upon this while investigating the performance of the `Remove` method in the docs. So decided to post an update.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a copy of the keys and not the entire dictionary as an array, like others have suggested.

```
mykeytype[] mykeys = new mykeytype[mydic.Keys.Count];
mydic.Keys.CopyTo(mykeys, 0);
foreach (var key in mykeys)
{
    MyType thing;
    if (!mydic.TryGetValue(key, out thing)) continue;

    // remove or add to dictionary here
}
```