# in foreach loop, should I expect an error since query collection has changed?

Tags: c#, linq

For example

```
       var query = myDic.Where(x => !blacklist.Contains(x.Key));
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            if (condition)
              blacklist.Add(item.key+1);  //key is int type
            ret.add(item);
        }
       return ret;
```

would this code be valid? and how do I improve it?

**Updated**

i am expecting my `blacklist.add(item.key+1)` would result in smaller `ret` then otherwise. The `ToList()` approach won't achieve my intention in this sense.
is there any other better ideas, correct and unambiguous.

Comment: Yes. Changing a collections internal objects is strictly prohibited when iterating over a collection.

Comment: If you insert the item into `blacklist`, would the updated contents of `blacklist` need to affect your subsequent loop iterations?

Comment: This is essentially the same as the other question you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176263/would-remove-a-key-from-dictionary-in-foreach-cause-a-problem-or-should-i-better ...answers explain that the collection cannot change once an enumerator is retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is perfectly safe to do and there shouldn't be any problems as you're not directly modifying the collection that you are iterating over.  Though you *are* making other changes that affects where clause, it's not going to blow up on you.

The query (as written) is lazily evaluated so `blacklist` is updated as you iterate through the collection and all following iterations will see any newly added items in the list as it is iterated.

The above code is effectively the same as this:

```
foreach (var item in myDic)
{
    if (!blacklist.Contains(item.Key))
    {
        if (condition)
            blacklist.Add(item.key + 1);
    }
}
```

So what you should get out of this is that as long as you are not directly modifying the collection that you are iterating over (the item after `in` in the `foreach` loop), what you are doing is safe.

If you're still not convinced, consider this and what would be written out to the console:

```
var blacklist = new HashSet<int>(Enumerable.Range(3, 100));
var query = Enumerable.Range(2, 98).Where(i => !blacklist.Contains(i));
foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    if ((item % 2) == 0)
    {
        var value = 2 * item;
        blacklist.Remove(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Changing a collections internal objects is strictly prohibited when iterating over a collection.

**UPDATE**

I initially made this a comment, but here is a further bit of information:

I should note that my knowledge comes from experience and articles I've read a long time ago. There is a chance that you can execute the code above because (I believe) the query contains references to the selected object within blacklist. blacklist might be able to change, but not query. If you were strictly iterating over blacklist, you would not be able to add to the blacklist collection.

Comment: This is correct, but he is not changing the iterated collection and therefore the code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as presented would not throw an exception. The collection being iterated (`myDic`) is not the collection being modified (`blacklist` or `ret`).

What will happen is that each iteration of the loop will evaluate the current item against the query predicate, which would inspect the `blacklist` collection to see if it contains the current item's key. This is lazily evaluated, so a change to `blacklist` in one iteration *will* potentially impact subsequent iterations, but it will not be an error. (`blacklist` is fully evaluated upon each iteration, its enumerator is not being held.)